# How to Bind TextBox with ComboBox's selected value which includes SQL join query

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My problem is like I have three SQL Server tables:

```
    ProductCategory
    ______________________
    CategoryID int PRIMARY KEY
    Category nvarchar(20)

    ProductDetails
    ______________________
    ProductID int PRIMARYKEY
    ProductName nvarchar(50)
    CategoryID int FOREIGN KEY
```

AND

```
    Asset
    _______________________
    ProductID int FOREIGN KEY
    CategoryID INT FOREIGN KEY
    ProductName nvarchar(20)
```

Now I have made a ComboBox which SELECTS all **ProductName(s)** from **ProductDetails** table. Next I have made a textbox of Category which should display the corresponding **'Category' Name** from the **ProductCategory** table.
 The XAML part of the ComboBox & Textbox are like:

```
    <combobox itemsource="{binding}" Name="ProductComboBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"/>
    <textbox Name="CatID" TextChanged="CatID_TextChanged">
```

So there will be a JOIN of **CategoryID** from **ProductDetails** and **ProductCategory** Table to get the **Category** name, as **ProductDetails.ProductName** will be selected by the user in ComboBox. Later all these values will be inserted into the **Asset** table.
Please suggest how to make the XAML and XAML.cs file of this case?
Thank You !

Comment: Well, what fields do you intend to display in your view? You should have the layout made up in your mind already.

Comment: I am making a form. The fields are Product Name (comboBox) , Category Name (TextBox). At the Submit button the values are inserted in the ASSET table, which has fields like --> ProductID, ProductName, CategoryID.
So as soon as the user selects the Product Name its corresponding Category Name must be displayed, but its CategoryID has to be inserted in the ASSET table on form submission. Hope I'm clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, usually when programming in WPF, you do not have much code in your code behind file (XAML.cs).

Instead you bind your view (xaml) to a class called view model.
The view model contains properties for the data which you want to display in your xaml.

I can only provide an overview of the steps you have to take because your question is very general.

- Create a view model class with the following properties:

  - a list of all products
  - the currently selected product
  - the category which belongs to the product
  - a list of all categories
- Create a view and bind your view elements to the respective properties of the view model
- When the currently selected product is set: set the category too
- When the user clicks "ok" (should by some `ICommand`): Store the data. The code which gets the data (the command) should be in the view model too.

**Useful links:**

See also this tutorial on MVVM and view models: [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Explained](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained)

This tutorial is about ComboBoxes and data binding: [WPF ComboBox and data binding](http://blog.cylewitruk.com/2010/09/wpf-combobox-and-databinding-datacontext-itemssource-displaymemberpath-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedvaluepath/)